Angular to display some content based on radio button selected
I have two radio buttons. When I select "Partially paid", then input element  formControlName="paidamount" will be displayed in screen along with <div class="formGroup". I have used binding, but this is not working.
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="fullypaid" [(ngModel)]="fullypaidvalue">
    <mat-radio-button value="true" [checked]="true">Fully Paid</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="false">Partially Paid</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
  <p>{{fullypaidvalue}}</p>
  <div class="formGroup" [class.d-none]="fullypaidvalue">
    <label for="paidamount" class="form-label" style="margin-top: 10pt;">Paid Amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control1" id="paidamount" formControlName="paidamount"
      placeholder="paidamount" name="paidamount" style="margin-left: 20pt;">
  </div>


My stackblitz link is
https://stackblitz.com/github/reegan2024/mygithubrepo?file=README.md
Can someone please help me

Simply change these values in the template:
<mat-radio-button value="true" [checked]="true">Fully Paid</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button value="false">Partially Paid</mat-radio-button>

for
<mat-radio-button [value]="true" [checked]="true">Fully Paid</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button [value]="false">Partially Paid</mat-radio-button>

As a sidenote, I notice that you use [(ngModel)] and formControlName on the same control. No need to mix. Your form is already built using the ReactiveForms module, keep it that way.
Remove [(ngModel)] and replace your binded value with this instead, in your component:
get fullypaidvalue(): boolean {
  return this.productFormarray.get('fullypaid')?.value;
}


[(ngModel)] or formControlName binds the value of the radio button as a string ("true" or "false"), not as a boolean (true or false).
you need to the variable to string : fullypaidvalue: string='true';
Also change the condition of d-none class to :  [class.d-none]="fullypaidvalue == 'true'"
